# How to insert value to the database table if their is any error, in the code?

Tags: php, mysql, class, loops, error-handling

Let me consider two tables

departments : It has two columns

```
-- id (primary key & auto increment)
-- name
```

-- logs :It has five columns

```
            -- id (primary key & auto increment)
            -- class name
            -- function name
            -- error message
            -- date
```

Now all i need to do now is if i get any error in the below code, my log table should be updated with 
respective class name,function name and message. How do i do that??

department.php

```
<?php
class Department
{
    public $db_connection = "";
    public function __construct()
    {
        $db_connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","emp_app");
        if($db_connection->connect_error)
            die("connection failed".$db_connection->connect_error); 
    }   
    public function create($name)
    {
        try{
            if($this->db_connection){
                $sql_query = "insert into departments (name) values ('$name')";
                if($this->database_connection->query($sql_query) == True){
                    $result["status"] = 1;
                    $result["message"] = "Department '".$department_name."' successfully inserted";
                }
                else{
                    $result["status"] = 0;
                    $result["message"] = "Couldn't add to the list.Sorry";
                }
            }
            else{
                throw new Exception("Database connection doesn't exist");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $error){
            $result["status"] = 0;
            $result["message"] = $error->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
include "department.php";
$connection = new Department();
$output = $connection->create("Testing");
if($output["status"] == 1){
    echo $output["message"];
}
else{   
    echo $output["message"];
    echo $output["message"];
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a class that contains one method that do `Insert` stuff to logs to that table. Call the method with few parameters like,

```
if($this->database_connection->query($sql_query) == True){
$result["status"] = 1;
$result["message"] = "Department '".$department_name."' successfully inserted";
 }
  else{
        $result["status"] = 0;
        $result["message"] = "Couldn't add to the list.Sorry";
        // here query fails, so do like
        // Anotherclass.doLog($classname, $functionname, $date);
        // assign $classname, $functionname based on the class and function & for date use date() function
 }
```

In `Anotherclass` you can have method like,

```
 public function doLog($classname, $fname, $date)
   {

    // insert query here

    }
```

Comment: Perfect idea... Well how to generate class name and function name, can u guide me ???

Comment: Simply declare a global variable for `className` since it's same for the entire method in that file ex : you are in department.php file, so set $className as department. For method, set methodName like, `$methodName = "create"`in each method. Just change $methodName = " change this name according to your method name " .

Comment: In case if my question was clear ,please do vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own error handler, and within it log errors into log file. Error handler function is triggered when error occurs.

[more info in php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: well i think @yuva cleared in simple way so i will go with him.